# How to make a picture box appear after 5 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wondering what coding i will use to make a picture appear after 5 seconds ?

For example

```
PictureBox1.visible = false
```

Then I want to wait 5 seconds before the picture becomes visible again

```
PictureBox1.visible = true
```

Could someone please put it into this code please

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    int horiz, vert, step;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //image is moved at each interval of the timer

        goblin.Left = goblin.Left + (horiz * step);
        goblin.Top = goblin.Top + (vert * step);


        // if goblin has hit the RHS edge, if so change direction left
        if ((goblin.Left + goblin.Width) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Width - step))
            horiz = -1;

        // if goblin has hit the LHS edge, if so change direction right
        if (goblin.Left <= step)
            horiz = 1;

        // if goblin has hit the bottom edge, if so change direction upwards
        if ((goblin.Top + goblin.Height) >= (Form1.ActiveForm.Height - step))
            vert = -1;

        // if goblin has hit the top edge, if so change direction downwards
        if (goblin.Top < step)
            vert = 1;
    }

    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Soon as the forms loads activate the goblin to start moving 
        //set the intial direction
        horiz = 1;  //start going right
        vert = 1;   //start going down
        step = 5;
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you seen the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) control?

Comment: Set a timer and change visibility when the timer ticks.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that easily, using [`async / await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) feature.

```
private async void YourFunction()
{
    PictureBox1.Visible = false;
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    PictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

Or, alternatively you can use a Timer:

```
private void YourFunction()
{
    Timer tm = new Timer();
    tm.Interval = 5000;
    tm.Tick += timerTick;
    PictureBox1.Visible = false;
    tm.Enabled = true;
    tm.Start();
}

private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox1.Visible = true;
    ((Timer) sender).Stop();
}
```

Comment: Async is truly a handy feature.

Comment: where would i put it in this

Comment: am i able to put it in hear ?

Comment: i must say i am a novice and what you do you mean by YourFunction() and what i dont know what i am doing with timerTick?

Comment: @user3574319 just copy paste the first code snippet into your code, but inside of your class not a to a method.then call that method from `Form_Load`.`YourFunction` is just the name of the function.you can change it however you like. the call it like: `YourFunctionName();`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This will make the entire application unresponsive!

Comment: That will block the UI thread for 5 seconds.

Comment: i want the form to load but the picture not to start until five seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
Private WithEvents tim As New System.Timers.Timer
    Public Delegate Sub doSub()
    Private thingToDo As doSub
    Dim tt = New ToolTip()

    Public Sub TimeOut(d As doSub, milliseconds As Integer)
        thingToDo = d
        tim.AutoReset = False
        tim.Interval = milliseconds
        tim.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tim_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tim.Elapsed
        Invoke(thingToDo)

    End Sub


    Private Sub hide()
        picturebox.hide()

    End Sub
    Private Sub show()
        TimeOut(Address of hide, 5000)

    End Sub
```

To C#
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 0):

using a backgroundworker so you will "freeze" thread in background and so it will make your application responsive.

take a look here :

```
 Private Sub Execute()
    Dim BGW As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler BGW.DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
    AddHandler BGW.ProgressChanged, AddressOf WorkerProgressChanged
    AddHandler BGW.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted

    With BGW
        .WorkerReportsProgress = True
        .WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        .RunWorkerAsync()
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub WorkerDoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    ' Do some work
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub

Private Sub WorkerProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ' I did something!
End Sub

Private Sub WorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    ' Show your picture here 
    Picturebox1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

That's all your application wont freeze and your gui will be responsive as well.Take a look also to ThreadPools or to Tasks in .net